# Adding or Injecting HTML or Component into Vue component generated at runtime

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, markdown

I have a Vue app where I take a bunch of markdown files and make them into Components that get dynamically generated and the links of which get handled by Vue Router. I'm loading my markdown using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tianyong90/vue-markdown-loader) Vue markdown loader.

The main route file looks like this:

```js
import RamblePosts from "@/assets/rambles/rambles.json"; // Simple JSON that contains the name of the markdown documents

...RamblePosts.map(entry => ({
    path: `/${entry}`,
    name: entry,
    component: () => import(`@/assets/rambles/${entry}.md`)
}))
];
```

As you can see, I'm generating components based off the markdown files I have in that directory.

Example usage would be:

```js
<template>
    <div class="wrapper-div rambling-wrapper">
        <div class="ramble-cards-wrapper">
            <RambleCard
                v-for="route in rambleList"
                :key="route.title"
                :title="route.title"
                :subtitle="route.subtitle"
                :ramble-url="route.url"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import RambleCard from "@/components/RambleCard";
    import rambleList from "@/assets/rambles/rambleList.json";

    export default {
        components: {
            RambleCard
        },
        data() {
            return {
                rambleList
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

This is a simple card element that just displays the name of the markdown entry, a subtitle and the vue-router link for it. Clicking on the link will take you to the relevant article, so something like `url.com/foo`

Is there a way for me to somehow edit or manipulate these markdown components and add, say, a Vue component to them or even just plain HTML? Since they're generated dynamically at, I'm not sure how to approach the situation because I can't just plug in a Component in the middle of those article components somewhere.